# speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher

Tags: 13.04, vmware

when I install Ubuntu 13.04 on VMWare, the installation procedure goes well, but in the end of the installation, instead of displaying the graphical interface the message bellow shows up:

```
acpid:exiting
speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
*asking all remaining processes to terminate...
```

I tried the installation three times but the problem persists.

Comment: Try to hit `Enter` in the machine. It probably fails to display the message to eject the CD. By pressing `Enter`, the (virtual) CD gets ejected and the (virtual) machines will be sent a reboot command.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error while installing. I just reset the virtual machine at that point and it started ok.